# Uninstall Android APK via AirWatch

Tags: android, permissions, uninstallation, airwatch

I´ve developed an APK which should be remotely managed via AirWatch. My problem is that I can install it successfully but I can´t uninstall it. Using AirWatch I can uninstall all apps in the device but this one. Is there any special permission/configuration I should have in the app to be able to uninstall it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remotely manage only "Managed" applications. Check the application's Assignment settings and ensure that you've selected the option to make the app managed.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will be an unmanaged app.

For uninstalling the unmanaged app, you need to provide the package name in uninstall application manifest for File/Action